# GWT GoogleMaps JavaScript API: overlay map type not visible

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, gwt

I'm trying to display a weather map in a GWT application. I'm using GWT 2.6.1 and the GWT wrapper of the GoogleMaps JavaScript API available [here](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/list) (gwt-maps-3.8.0-pre1.zip).

I'm trying to use a tile server, exactly like [this example](https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/ogc/googlemaps_v3.html). I view the source, and I see that they add the weather using an overlay image map type:

```
goes = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
            getTileUrl: function(tile, zoom) {
                return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/goes-east-vis-1km-900913/" + zoom + "/" + tile.x + "/" + tile.y +".png?"+ (new Date()).getTime(); 
            },
            tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
            opacity:0.60,
            name : 'GOES East Vis',
            isPng: true
        });
        map.overlayMapTypes.setAt("0",goes);
```

I'm also looking at examples of how to overlay an image map type from [google's tutorials](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay), and their approach is pretty much the same:

```
var imageMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
      if (zoom < 17 || zoom > 20 ||
          bounds[zoom][0][0] > coord.x || coord.x > bounds[zoom][0][1] ||
          bounds[zoom][1][0] > coord.y || coord.y > bounds[zoom][1][1]) {
        return null;
      }

      return ['http://www.gstatic.com/io2010maps/tiles/5/L2_',
          zoom, '_', coord.x, '_', coord.y, '.png'].join('');
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
  });

  map.overlayMapTypes.push(imageMapType);
```

I try to do this using the GWT wrapper:

```
package com.test.client;

import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader;
import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader.AjaxLoaderOptions;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.GoogleMap;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.ImageMapType;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.ImageMapTypeOptions;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.ImageMapTypeOptions.Callback;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapOptions;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapTypeId;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.Point;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.Size;

public class GwtTest implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        AjaxLoaderOptions options = AjaxLoaderOptions.newInstance();
        options.setOtherParms("sensor=false");
        Runnable callback = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createMap();
            }
        };
        AjaxLoader.loadApi("maps", "3", callback, options);
    }

    public void createMap() {

        MapOptions mapOpts = MapOptions.create();
        mapOpts.setZoom(4);
        mapOpts.setCenter(LatLng.create(37.09024, -95.712891));
        mapOpts.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        mapOpts.setStreetViewControl(false);

        final GoogleMap map = GoogleMap.create(Document.get().getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOpts);

        ImageMapTypeOptions imto = ImageMapTypeOptions.create();
        imto.setGetTileUrl(new Callback(){

            @Override
            public String handle(Point coord, double z) {
                return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913/"+ z + "/" + coord.getX() + "/" + coord.getY() + ".png";
            }

        });
        imto.setTileSize(Size.create(256, 256));

        ImageMapType imt = ImageMapType.create(imto);

        map.getOverlayMapTypes().push(imt);
    }
}
```

However, I get a compiler error on that last line:

```
The method push(MapType) in the type MVCArray<MapType> is not applicable for the arguments (ImageMapType)
```

It appears that the GWT wrapper is missing some inheritance and doesn't recognize an ImageMapType as a MapType. So I try to do this in native JavaScript:

```
package com.test.client;

import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader;
import com.google.gwt.ajaxloader.client.AjaxLoader.AjaxLoaderOptions;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.GoogleMap;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.ImageMapType;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.ImageMapTypeOptions;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.ImageMapTypeOptions.Callback;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.LatLng;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapOptions;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.MapTypeId;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.Point;
import com.google.maps.gwt.client.Size;

public class GwtTest implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        AjaxLoaderOptions options = AjaxLoaderOptions.newInstance();
        options.setOtherParms("sensor=false");
        Runnable callback = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createMap();
            }
        };
        AjaxLoader.loadApi("maps", "3", callback, options);
    }

    public void createMap() {

        MapOptions mapOpts = MapOptions.create();
        mapOpts.setZoom(4);
        mapOpts.setCenter(LatLng.create(37.09024, -95.712891));
        mapOpts.setMapTypeId(MapTypeId.TERRAIN);
        mapOpts.setStreetViewControl(false);

        final GoogleMap map = GoogleMap.create(Document.get().getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOpts);
        addWeatherLayer(map);   
    }

    public native void addWeatherLayer(GoogleMap map) /*-{
        var imageMapType = new $wnd.google.maps.ImageMapType({
            getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
            console.log("http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913/"+ zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png");
            "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913/"+ zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png";
            },
            tileSize: new $wnd.google.maps.Size(256, 256),
            isPng: true
        });

        map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, imageMapType);

    }-*/;
}
```

This code actually runs. If I view the JavaScript console while viewing the map, I can see the printouts of the tile server URLs, and they are correct. However, no weather is visible on the map.

So, my questions are:

- Is there a way to do this in "pure GWT" using the GWT wrapper and no native JavaScript?
- While using the native JavaScript, why isn't my weather visible? I've checked to make sure that there is weather that should be visible, but it never displays on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was an idiot and forgot the **return** keyword in the `getTileUrl` function:

```
public native void addWeatherLayer(GoogleMap map) /*-{
        var imageMapType = new $wnd.google.maps.ImageMapType({
            getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
            return "http://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cache/tile.py/1.0.0/nexrad-n0q-900913/"+ zoom + "/" + coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png";
            },
            tileSize: new $wnd.google.maps.Size(256, 256),
            isPng: true
        });

        map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, imageMapType);

    }-*/;
```

I'd still be curious to hear about a "pure GWT" solution, but for now, this works.